# Lottery program that generates 6 random numbers between 1 and 59 C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have created a simple program which randomly generates 6 winning numbers. While the program works, I would also like for it to ensure that the same number isn't outputted twice as well as sorting them into numerical order when outputted. How would I go about doing such a thing while sticking to similar techniques already used? My code is down below. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
        int temp;
        int[] lotto = new int[6];

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            temp = rand.Next(1, 59);
            lotto[i] = temp;
        }
        Console.Write($"The lotterry winning numbers are: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(lotto[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: The typical solution is to create a sequence with the possible values in order. Then **shuffle** the sequence and take the first N values.

Comment: I agree with @JoelCoehoorn, take a look at Fisher Yates shuffle algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        int temp;
        int[] lotto = new int[6];

        Random rand = new Random();
         
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 6)
        {
            temp = rand.Next(1, 59);
            //check if lotto contains just generated number, if so skip that number

            bool alreadyExist = false;
            foreach (int item in lotto)
            {
                if (item == temp)
                {
                    alreadyExist = true; 
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (alreadyExist)
                continue;                

            lotto[i] = temp;
            i++;
        }
        Console.Write($"The lotterry winning numbers are: ");

        // Sort array in ascending order.
        Array.Sort(lotto);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(lotto[j] + " ");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I get an error for the lotto.contains section of the code.

Comment: You need to add import statement  at the top of the file "using System.Linq;" to use contains method.

Comment: is there a way to do it without the linq statement?

Comment: yes, I made changes not to use LINQ, pls see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Based on a Fisher-Yates shuffle, but saves some work because we know we don't need all the values (if we only need 6 values out of 10 million potentials, we only need to take the first six iterations of the fisher-yates algorithm).

```
public IEnumerable<int> DrawNumbers(int count, int MaxNumbers)
{
    var r = new Random(); //ideally, make this a static member somewhere
    var possibles = Enumerable.Range(1, MaxNumbers).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var index = r.Next(i, MaxNumbers);
        yield return possibles[index];
        possibles[index] = possibles[i];
    }
}

var lottoNumbers = DrawNumbers(6, 59);
Console.Write("The lotterry winning numbers are: ");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", lottoNumbers.OrderBy(n => n)));
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/NXYkpU

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq to create sequence [1..59] and order it by random to shuffle it.

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        var winners = Enumerable.Range(1, 59)
            .OrderBy(x => rand.Next())
            .Take(6)
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", winners));
```

Comment: Rare case when we sort (`OrderBy`) twice.

Comment: First time to "randomize", second time to order resulting shuffled array in ascending order. 
But @Jencer, be aware that this solution is far from optimal, only use it on short arrays. For longer arrays or frequent use, please look for Fisher-Yates method as suggested above.

Comment: how do I do it without using linq?

Comment: Please see [Fisher–Yates algorithm in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle), there are some examples in pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it Dmitri's way because it is quick and obvious and performance isn't that important with an array this size.

But just for fun, this is slightly more efficient.

```
IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers(int min, int max, int count)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var size = max - min + 1;
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(min, size).ToArray();
    while (count > 0)
    {
        size--;
        var index = random.Next(0, size);
        yield return numbers[index];
        numbers[index] = numbers[size];
        count--;
    }
}
```

This solution creates an array containing all possible values and selects them randomly. Each time a selection is made, the array is "shrunk" by moving the last element to replace the element that was chosen, preventing duplicates.

To use:

```
var numbers = GetNumbers(1, 59, 6).ToList();
foreach (var number in numbers.OrderBy(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the way you've done it. I don't understand what the new stuff is like Var?

Comment: `var` declares a variable, just like `int` or `string`. The difference is that with `var` the compiler will [infer the data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables). In most of my code it would be equivalent to replace `var` with `int`.

Comment: what would i need to change about your answer to make it work with what i already posted?